# Event click on href <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento, jquery-events

I have a question about Javascript event here. I have an `<a>` tag like this:

`<a id='aTag' href='http://example.com'>Click to redirect</a>`

Then I call an event like:

```
<script>
$('#aTag').click();
//or
$('#aTag').trigger('click');
</script>
```

It does not redirect me to `http://example.com`. I tried to add an `onClick()` event in the `<a>` tag like this:

```
<a id='aTag' href='http://example.com' onclick='alert("Event happened");'>Click to redirect</a>
```

And then call the `.click()` event. It shows me `alert("Event happened")`;

Can anyone show me how to call the `.click()` event correctly, or correct this redirect with issue with the `href` in that `<a>` tag?

In my business I just need an `<a>` tag, so not with the `window.open` or `windown.location`.

Comment: Why you need an event at first place to redirect?

Comment: like @Mr.Alien says, get rid of the jquery script and it will work as it is: http://jsfiddle.net/AdPtj/

Answer (score 4):

## Explanation

Redirects can only happen if the user clicks **directly** on the link. Programmatic or deferred `click` triggers do not work.

An alternative would be:

- to change directly the `window.location`
- to open the link in a new tab/window

### Changing `window.location`

```
window.location="http://wherever.you/want/to/g0";
```

or

```
 window.location=$('a.selector').attr('href'); // to use a link's address
```

### New tab/window

You cannot programmatically (`click()` or `trigger`) open new tabs/ windows or redirect. They get (ad-)blocked. automatically

So new tab/window openings always have to be triggered by user action. (Otherwise we'd always be full with popup ads)

So 1st of all, make sure that your js is executed on a user event, and then you should be able to use `window.open`.

## [JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/V9APL/)

### html:

```
<a href="//google.com" target="blank">new tab google</a>

<button class="user">user triggered</button>
<button class="programatic">programatic</button>
```

### js:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked', e);
    // unfortunately although we simulated 
    // the click on the <a/> , it will still 
    // not launch a new window - idk why.
    // therefore we can use the line below
    // to open the <a>'s href in a new tab/window
    // NOTE: this will only occur if the execution was
    // triggered by the user
    window.open(e.currentTarget.href);
});

var simulateClick = function(origEv) {
    var e = $.Event("click");
    e.ctrlKey = true;
    e.metaKey = true;
    e.originalEvent = origEv;
    $('a').trigger(e);
};

$('button.user').on('click', function(e) {
    // this call will actually open a window
    simulateClick(e);
});

$('button.programatic').on('click', function(e) {
    // this will result in a blocked popup
    $.get('/someurl').always(function() {
        // executes the method after a non-user event
        // results in blocked popup
        simulateClick(e);
    });
});

// this will result in a blocked popup
setTimeout(simulateClick, 1000);
```

Comment: I don't think he is trying to open new tab, the OP is trying to redirect. In his words - "It does not redirect me to 'http://mylink.com'. "

Answer (score 1):

Try this  -

```
<a id="aTag" href="http://mylink.com" onclick="return doWork();">Click to redirect</a>
<script>
    function doWork(){
          //... do your works
          return true; // then return true to redirect
    }
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gcJ73/

(Though the fiddle attributes are a little different to show you that it works)

or with jQuery:

```
//first assign the click handler
$('#aTag').click(function(){
    //... do your work
    return true;
});

//then call programmatically
$("#aTag").click(); or  $("#aTag").trigger("click");
```

BTW programatically calling it will not redirect. Will just call the event handler, not redirect.

jQuery fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gcJ73/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
    jQuery('#aTag').click(function() {
        // Your Code
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery('#aTag').click() does not execute the `href` attribute of an anchor tag so you will not be redirected, do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#aTag').click( function (e) {
        window.location.href = this.href;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id='aTag' href='http://mylink.com' onclick="location.href='http://mylink.com';">
Click to redirect
</a>
```

check this code snippet, also it will work like what you want to do.